# How to split git log output into an array of commits in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, split

I'm not good at bash, and what I was trying to do is to get information from `git log --name-status branch_one...branch_two` and after that split output by commits, for example:

```
git_command_output="
commit one
Author: Johny
Date: 01/01/1999

feat: add something

M src/some_file.txt

commit two
Author: Alex
Date: 02/01/1999

fix: bug

M src/some_file.txt"
```

From the above I would want to create and `array` of strings, where each string will be information about one commit.

For instance `array` would look something like that:

```
echo "${array[0]}" 

# Author: Johny
# Date: 01/01/1999

# feat: add something

# M src/my_file.txt

echo "${array[1]}" 

# Author: Alex
# Date: 02/01/1999

# fix: bug

# M src/foreign_file.txt
```

What I tried (didn't work):

`array[0]=$(echo "$git_command_output" | awk '{split($0, array, "commit"); print array[0]}')`

`IFS='commit' read -r -a array <<< "$git_command_output"`

Is there a concise way to do it, preferably using `awk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `readarray` with `awk`:

```bash
IFS= readarray -d '' -t arr < <(awk -v RS='\nM [^\n]+\n' '{ORS = RT "\0"} 1' file)

# check array content
declare -p arr

declare -a arr=([0]=$'commit one\nAuthor: Johny\nDate: 01/01/1999\n\nfeat: add something\n\nM src/some_file.txt\n' [1]=$'\ncommit two\nAuthor: Alex\nDate: 02/01/1999\n\nfix: bug\n\nM src/some_file.txt\n')
```

Here:

- We add `\0` after each record using awk
- Then use `-d ''` to make sure to read `\0` delimited text in array `arr`

Another simpler any-version `awk` would be:

```bash
IFS= readarray -d '' -t arr < <(awk '{printf "%s", $0 (/^M / ? "\0" : ORS)}' file)
```

Comment: I'm experimenting now, for some reason `"${arr[0]}"` shows the whole contents, while `"${arr[1]}"` shows none

Comment: Please check your `awk` and `bash` versions. It requires `gnu-awk` and bash 4+

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing, but read from a string variable instead of a `file`? -

Comment: Yes sure, just replace `awk -v RS='\nM [^\n]+\n' '{ORS = RT "\0"} 1' file` with `awk -v RS='\nM [^\n]+\n' '{ORS = RT "\0"} 1' <<< "$string"`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the output of many `git` commands (such as `log`) to those that affect specific files, simply by adding the paths of these files at the end of the command. Try:

```
git log --name-status branch_one...branch_two -- src/my_file.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to remove part with filtering by modified file, but it's really helpful. Thank you!